# making word cloud in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, cpu-word, word-cloud

I want to create a word cloud in flutter.
Is there a way to make it?
For instance, if I have a list

```
List words = ['banana','banana','banana','banana','purple','orange','apple','apple','green']
```

I want elements repeated several times to be shown in a big font, and elements repeated a few times to be shown in a small font.

Comment: search for `word cloud "api"` - the first few hits give you an online generator with HTTP interface, and a JavaScript implementation that you could port to Dart / dart:ui

Comment: Just compute the fontSize according to repeated times: Text(word, style: TextStyle(fontSize: calculateFontSizeAccordingToCount(countof(word))))

Answer (score 5):

I needed to create a word cloud in Flutter, so I created this package: https://github.com/letsar/flutter_scatter

You can create a word cloud like this:

```
class WordCloudExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> widgets = <Widget>[];
    for (var i = 0; i < kFlutterHashtags.length; i++) {
      widgets.add(ScatterItem(kFlutterHashtags[i], i));
    }

    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final ratio = screenSize.width / screenSize.height;

    return Center(
      child: FittedBox(
        child: Scatter(
          fillGaps: true,
          delegate: ArchimedeanSpiralScatterDelegate(ratio: ratio),
          children: widgets,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScatterItem extends StatelessWidget {
  ScatterItem(this.hashtag, this.index);
  final FlutterHashtag hashtag;
  final int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle style = Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.copyWith(
          fontSize: hashtag.size.toDouble(),
          color: hashtag.color,
        );
    return RotatedBox(
      quarterTurns: hashtag.rotated ? 1 : 0,
      child: Text(
        hashtag.hashtag,
        style: style,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And you will end up with the following layout:
[image: word_cloud]